# How to remove a Gigwage client eslint error with nestJS?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

whe I use the gigwage client on the services I receive the following error in from the eslint:

`TS2742: The inferred type of 'findAll' cannot be named without a reference to '@gigwage/client/node_modules/axios'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary`

```
async findAll(findContractorsDto: FindContractorsDto) {
  try {
    return this.gigwageClient.get<{ contractors: Contractor[] }>(
      '/contractors?per_page=10&page=1',
    );
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.error(e);
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}
```

Basically, a way to remove that eslint error, somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the function an explicit type. In this case, it would be `Promise` containing an `AxiosResponse`.

```
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

async function findAll(findContractorsDto: FindContractorsDto): Promise<
  AxiosResponse<{ contractors: Contractor[]; }, any>
> {
  /* ... */
}
```

You might need to import that type from `axios`.